# using uiview as property.. its null what am i doing wrong

Tags: iphone, ios, objective-c, uiview

Why is blackview always null?

```
@property (strong, nonatomic) UIView *blackView;

[_blackView setFrame:self.view.bounds];
[_blackView setBackgroundColor:[UIColor colorWithWhite:0 alpha:0.8]];
[self.view addSubview:_blackView];
 NSLog(@"%@", _blackView);  // i get null
```

I was instantiating it using alloc init before but i need to access this view between methods so i am using it as a property

Comment: `_blackView` hasn't been set to a non-nil object to begin with?..

Comment: no this is the first time im referencing it..

Comment: It's the problem then: you need to initialize the `_blackView` variable either directly or by assigning the `blackView` property, otherwise it remains `nil`, and all methods that you call on it are ignored.

Comment: i was under the impression since i'm setting it as a property then its initialized and i can use it.  what else do i need to do?

Comment: i used alloc init and got it to work.. is that correct practice?

Comment: Declaring a property simply creates the storage, and gives you a getter and/or a setter. Other than that, it's like an instance variable: you need to set it explicitly before using it.

Comment: i understand.. thanks so much.  i know this is basic but i usually create views in IB and i dont usually need to initialize them when i add them as a property that way

Comment: Yes, adding alloc/init in the designated initializer of the object containing the property is the typical thing to do.

Comment: property is just automatic set your setter/getter, and give some property like strong/weak, you still alloc init your ivar

Answer (score 3):

Try using `self.blackview` and initialize

`self.blackview = [[UIView alloc] initWithFrame:self.view.frame];`

Answer (score 1):

Before you do anything to the object(UIView). You must allcate momery for it, and do some initializations. Use alloc and init method. Like:

```
UIView *blackView = [[UIView alloc] initWithFrame:CGrectMake( , , , )];
```

Answer (score 1):

I must say, this is something that even the beginners should know.

After you have created a property. Make sure you have **synthesized** it.

```
@synthesize blackView;
```

And then make sure you alloc some memory to it atleast, use

```
self.blackView = [[UIView alloc]init];
```

And then you can perform, any function on it, that you want.

Comment: In current versions of Clang, properties are automatically synthesised unless you write the accessor(s) yourself.  So the first bit of your answer is no longer necessary.

Comment: true that, but i thought.. it was a good thing to keep the basics right :)

Comment: Yes, I don't necessarily think auto synthesizing is a Good Thing.

Answer (score 0):

```
@property (strong, nonatomic) UIView *blackView;
```

Here you have made the `decalaration`. But that does not mean that you have allocated any `memory` to it.

In your implementation file you need to `allocate memory` to it and `initialise` it as well.
If you are using XCode version 6 and above you dont need to synthesize your property because that is done by Xcode itself.
Otherwise you need to syntesize your property.

```
@synthesize blackView;

self.blackView = [UIView alloc]initWithFrame:self.view.bounds];
```

Also if you have a nib file, and there you have alraedy added a `UiView` and you want it to be your `blackView` then you have to make an `IBoutlet` Connection from your nib file to your .h file. in this case you dont need to `initialise` or `allocate` memory to your UIView object. That is done by `iOS SDk` itself.